# Can we highlight today's day in Resource view in Fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Can we highlight today's day in Resource view in Fullcalendar?
If I highlight using `.fc-day-today` class I'm not able to see borders for resource slot. You can see that in the CodePen link below as well.
Can we do something like we have in `timeGrid` views?

[image]

I tried **Now-Indicator Render Hooks** but it just highlights the start of the day. You can see it in in this [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/navneerajmishra/pen/qBLPoYz?editors=0110).

CSS:

```
.fc-day-today {
  background: #ddd
}
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener(
'DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

    timeZone: 'UTC',
    initialView: 'peopleTimeLineMonth',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'peopleTimeLineMonth'
    },
    views: {
      peopleTimeLineMonth: {
            type: 'resourceTimeline',
            titleFormat: { month: 'long', year: 'numeric' },
            duration: { month: 1 },
            buttonText: 'Month',
            slotLabelFormat: [{ weekday: 'short' }, { day: 'numeric' }],
            slotLabelInterval: { days: 1 },
            slotMinWidth: 40,
            eventMaxStack: 1,
            dayPopoverFormat: 'D',
            nowIndicator: true,
            now: new Date(),
            
          },
    },
    resources: [
      { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
      { id: 'b', title: 'Room B' }
    ],
    events: '/api/demo-feeds/events.json?with-resources=2'
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

Is there a way to move the now indicator to the right considering the time of the day as well?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.